# Cannot pod spec lint because of undeclared type errors

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, nsfetchedresultscontroller, uiwindow

I'm trying to create a pod, witch rely on other pod to compile (`JSQSystemSoundPlayer`, `JSQMessagesViewController`, `XMPPFramework`)

I must add that the source code is written in `Swift (1.2)`, on `Xcode 6.3.2` and I'm using `cocoapod 0.34.4` (`XMPPFramework` won't compile on the latest build (looped import))

I'm getting errors like this when I use the following command `pod trunk push podname.podspec --verbose` : *podname has been changed*

```
error: use of undeclared type 'NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate'
error: use of undeclared type 'UIWindow'
[!] The podspec does not validate.
```

Here is my pod : *podname has been changed*

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
use_frameworks!

target 'target_example', :exclusive => true do
  pod "podname", :path => "../"
    pod "JSQSystemSoundPlayer"
    pod "JSQMessagesViewController"
    pod "XMPPFramework"
    pod "FMDB"
end
```

Here is my podSpec : *podname has been changed*

```
#
# Be sure to run `pod lib lint pod.podspec' to ensure this is a
# valid spec and remove all comments before submitting the spec.
#
# Any lines starting with a # are optional, but encouraged
#
# To learn more about a Podspec see http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html
#

Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = "podname"
  s.version          = "0.1.0"
  s.summary          = "Summary"
  s.description      = <<-DESC
                       desc
                       DESC
  s.homepage         = "https://github.com/company/project"
  s.license          = 'MIT'
  s.author           = { "company" => "mail" }
  s.source           = { :git => "https://github.com/company/project.git", :tag => "master" }

  s.platform     = :ios, '8.0'
  s.requires_arc = true

  s.source_files = 'Pod/Classes/**/*'
  s.frameworks = 'Foundation', 'CoreData', 'UIKit'
  s.dependency 'FMDB', '~> 1.0'
  s.dependency 'JSQMessagesViewController', '~> 6.1.3'
  s.dependency 'JSQSystemSoundPlayer', '~> 2.0.0'
  s.dependency 'XMPPFramework'

end
```

All helps are appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those errors were linked with the absence of `libxml` anywhere in the `Podspec`, I fixed it by adding the following to my `Podspec` file:

```
s.libraries = 'xml2'
s.xcconfig = {
'HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS' => '$(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2'
}
```